# Trying to Create Paging Buttons With Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination

I am trying to create pagination in my Vue application. How I am trying to do this is I have a data variable in Vue called postCount. This will equal the amount of posts pulled back from an API. I also have a data variable called perPage that is set to 10 so 10 posts should show up per page. What I am trying to then do is take those two data variables and do postCount divided by perPage and get a number. I then want to take that number and create that many buttons to have for pagination.

I assume for this I would use 'v-for' in Vue just not sure the best way to execute this populating the correct amount of pagination buttons based on the number dividing postCount by perPage.

So as an example if postCount = 200 and perPage = 10, then a pages data variable would then equal 20 and 20 pagination buttons would be displayed.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

Answer (score 0):

Set some sensible defaults.

```
data: ({
  posts: [],
  pagination: {
    per: 10,
    current: 0,
    total: 0
  } 
})
```

Now let's get our posts back with a simple method:

```
async getPosts() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/posts')

    this.posts = data.posts
    this.pagination.total = data.posts.length
  } catch (e) {
    // console.log(e)
  }
}
```

and create some computed properties to determine which should be visible:

```
computed: {
  postsToShow: {
    get: function() {
      return this.posts.slice(current, per)
    }
  }
}
```

And update our `v-for`:

```
v-for="posts in postsToShow"
```

Now let's add a select item to determine how many posts to show at a time.

```
<select v-model="postsPerPage">
    <option value="10"> 10 </option>
    <option value="20"> 20 </option>
</select>
```

And add the appropriate getter/setter

```
computed: {
  postsPerPage: {
    get: function() {
      return this.pagination.per
    },
    set: function(per) {
      this.pagination.per = per
    }
  }
}
```

And buttons to cycle through the pages:

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="nextPage"> Next </a>
<a href="#" @click.prevent="previousPage"> Previous </a>
```

And their corresponding functions:

```
nextPage() {
  this.pagination.current = (this.pagination.current * this.per < this.total) ? this.current++ : this.current
}

previousPage() {
  this.pagination.current = (this.pagination.current > 0) ? this.pagination.current-- : 0
}
```

And let's display buttons for navigating directly to a specific page:

```
<a href="#" v-for="p in (pagination.total / pagination.per)" v-text="p" @click.prevent="setCurrent(p)"></a>
```

And our corresponding method:

```
setCurrent(page) {
  this.paginagation.current = page
}
```